# List all the possible values for $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}f_k(x)dx$ under these conditions...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question**: Let $\{f_k(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of nonnegative functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_k(x)=\frac{1}{k}$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_k(x)dx=1$.  List all the possible values for $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}f_k(x)dx$.

**My Thoughts**:  I am a bit confused on how we are going to relate the supremum over $x\in\mathbb{R}$ of $f_k(x)$, as in the hypothesis, and the supremum over $k\in\mathbb{N}$ of $f_k(x)$, as in what we are trying to prove... are they the same?   Since the $f_k$'s are integrable, we can say they are measurable, so the Monotone Convergence Theorem would imply, I believe, that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_k(x)dx=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{k}$ (maybe I can't put that supremum inside the integral like that....)  But then I am not sure how to use $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_k(x)dx=1$....  any help is greatly apprecaited!  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is meant to be $\{\infty\}$.  Suppose
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} \sup_{k} f_k = I < \infty. $$
By the monotone convergence theorem, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that
$$ \int_{[-n,n]} \sup_{k} f_k \ge I-\tfrac13. $$
Now consider $f_{6n}$.  Since $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} f_{6n}(x) \le \frac1{6n}$, we see that $\int_{[-n,n]} f_{6n} \le \frac13$.  Therefore
\begin{align} \int_{\mathbb R} \sup_{k} f_k &= \int_{[-n,n]} \sup_{k} f_k + \int_{\mathbb R \setminus [-n,n]} \sup_{k} f_k \\&\ge \int_{[-n,n]} \sup_{k} f_k + \int_{\mathbb R \setminus [-n,n]} f_{6n} \\&\ge I - \tfrac13 + \tfrac23 \\&= I + \tfrac13.\end{align}

Comment: I have two questions: 
1. Why can we say that $\int_{[-n,n]}f_{6n}\leq\frac{1}{3}$?  In particular, how does that follow from $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_{6n}(x)\leq\frac{1}{6n}$?
2. Why can we say that $\int_{\mathbb{R}-[-n,n]}f_{6n}\leq\frac{2}{3}$?  Is that because if we take, for a very large $n$, we can safely assume that the measure of what we are then integrating over is, at least, $1$, so using the inequality at the end of line $5$, we get what I am asking about?  

Thank you!

Comment: @User7238 1.  $\int_A f \le |A| \|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: @User7238 2.  It is $\ge$.  If $A \subset B$, then $\int_{B-A} f = \int_B f - \int _A f$.

Comment: perfect!  Thank you so much!